# How to programmatically select local file in input type="file"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want read a local txt file with javascript on chrome browser. So, I use `<input type="file" .../>` and when I select any txt file, I read it. But I dont want select file. I need to load the file with the file path. How is this possible?
Thanks

Comment: javascript running in a browser doesn't have unmitigated access to the files on the filesystem.

Comment: I am not quite sure how to do it in Vanilla JavaScipt .. But using jQuery, you could use something like: `$('#your_div').load("path/to/file/textfile.txt");`  --  AND this file MUST reside on the outward facing side of the website ...  Otherwise @RJM is correct ..

Comment: If selecting the file in the dialog takes too much time and it bothers you you can implement drag and drop

Comment: @Zak, I don't think that works for local files, just files on the server.  (Sorry, just saw your edit)  :-)

Answer (score 6):

You can't do this. This is obviously because of security implications: imagine if any website you visit could read your FileZilla preferences file, which contains all your unencrypted FTP passwords? I bet you wouldn't like that.

You have to obtain a `File` reference (e.g. from an event handler) before being able to manipulate it. [More info](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I was create FileZilla server and ftp, after I create txt file and write any text in this txt file from ftp. But I cant read it with javascript. How can I read txt file from ftp with username and password. @christophetd

Comment: Under windows it is located under `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\FileZilla\sitemanager.xml`. The passwords are base64 encoded.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to read file data opened from file dialog:

```
function readFile(){
    var t = document.getElementById("file")

    var o = new FileReader();
    o.onload = function(t) {
        console.log(t.target.result);
    }
    o.readAsText(t.files[0]);
}
```

edit: you can't just open files without selecting it first